# Selecting dates(mm-dd-yyyy) this month from mongodb

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

How can I select the dates from my mongodb for this month only, I have a `date:{type:String}` and my format is: `mm-dd-yyyy` ex: `09-03-2019`:

Here is my router to get the distinct dates then count them, but not for monthly:

```
router.get('/blooddonationarea', function(req, res) {
    sess=req.session;
    Blooddonation.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$date" , count :{$sum:1}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, date) {     
    res.json({ success: true, date: date });

    });       
});
```

**yields to:**

```
[ { _id: '04-11-2019', count6: 1 },
  { _id: '05-21-2019', count6: 1 },
  { _id: '10-11-2019', count6: 3 },
  { _id: '10-22-2019', count6: 1 } ]
```

My desired output is to display the dates for example where `date = month.now()` then it will only show months for 01-dd-yyyy only.

I tried this :

```
const startOfMonth = moment().startOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
const endOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY')

        Blooddonation.aggregate([
        { "$match": {
            "date": { "$gte": startOfMonth, "$lte": endOfMonth }
        }},
        { "$group": { "_id": "$date", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }],function(err, date) {     
            res.json({ success: true, date: date });
            console.log("dates are" + date);
        });              
    });
```

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT No it will not work. As it will retrieve the data from the last year as well.

Comment: oh ok my bad, read it too fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`moment`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library to get the desired format and then use `$gte` and `$lte` operator to get the data for the current month only

```
const moment = require('moment')

const startOfMonth = moment().startOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY')
const endOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY')

Blooddonation.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "date": { "$gte": startOfMonth, "$lte": endOfMonth }
  }}
  { "$group": { "_id": "$date", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Comment: when i tried to console this is gives me : [object Object]

Comment: Have you used the callback or promise to get the result. I think you are getting either cursor or promise!!

Comment: can you look up my edit, I pasted there what I tried

Comment: Try this `Blooddonation.aggregate([...]).toArray().then((data) => console.log(data))` If you are not using mongoose.

Comment: still gives me [object Object], whatever I try, weird

Comment: but it works when I try to  render it to my chart, it's weird but I'll just accept this

Comment: but it outputs last year months haha, like january 2018, january 2017